# Div Para Imprimir

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando um código em JS que funciona muito bem para imprimir:

```
function printdiv(divID) {
    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body>";
    var newstr = document.all.item(divID).innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    return false;
}
```

Só que preciso imprimir alguns títulos e haverá vezes que terei que imprimir mais de um *grid*. Então criei no CSS o "print" e o "no print" e coloco tudo dentro da DIV `divID`.

O que acontece, é que quando o *grid* é populado com muitos dados aparecendo barra de rolagem ou a paginação ele não imprime tudo.

Com o grid todo populado, só que se eu coloco somente o grid dentro dessa `div`, ele imprime todos os dados.

Já tentei de várias formas e todas acontecem esse problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui desta forma:

```js
GridSuprimento.DataSource = gridCarregaSuprimento();
            GridSuprimento.AllowPaging = false;
            GridSuprimento.DataBind();
            GridRetirada.DataSource = gridCarregaRetirada();
            GridRetirada.AllowPaging = false;
            GridRetirada.DataBind();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            GridSuprimento.RenderControl(hw);
            GridRetirada.RenderControl(hw);
            string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
            sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
            sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
            sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
            sb.Append(lblTitulo.Text);
            sb.Append(gridHTML);
            sb.Append("\");");
            sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
            sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
            sb.Append("printWin.print();");
            sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());
```